# Structure for a test suite

Tags: python

In the below mentioned directory structure i am trying to build a python platform for a test module.The code resides in the directory /opt/site which is included in the python path.

In the /opt/site directory i also have a `__init__` file and another file as suite.py along with directories dir1,dir2

In dir1,dir2 directories i have the following files `__init__` and execute.py

My question is that what should be the code on suite.py such that if i mention dir1 in suite.py dir1/execute.py should be executed and if dir2 is mentioned dir2/execute.py should be executed or if both are mentioned then dir1/execute.py and dir2/execute.py should be executed

Also how to call particular functions in dir1/execute.py from suite.py

can any one let me know how to achieve this

Comment: What exactly "build a python platform for a test module" means? Do you have a module you want to test or do you want to build a generic test framework?

Comment: Yes want o build a generic framework so that people can add inteait own modules later from suite.py.Please let me know about this..

Comment: Are you aware of the tons of tools already existent? (http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy) unittest, py.test, nose, they already do what you want, maybe the others too.

Comment: this is too generic i want to build it from scratch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your directory structure looks like that:

```
-+- dir1
 |   |
 |   +- execute.py
 |
 +- dir2
 |   |
 |   +- execute.py
 |
 +- __init__.py
 |
 +- suite.py
```

### Solution

If my assumptions are correct and your directory structure matches the one mentioned above, you could place empty `__init__.py` files in both `dir1` and `dir2` directories and then, within `suite.py` execute the files you want like that:

```
from dir1 import execute as execute1
from dir2 import execute as execute2
```

This will import both `execute.py` files, which means they will be executed. To execute already imported modules again, just use `reload()` on the variable representing a module (eg. `reload(execute1)`).

### Explanation

What you did by putting `__init__.py` in both `dir1` and `dir2` directories is that you informed Python that both `dir1` and `dir2` should be treated as modules. And because they are modules, you can simply import their submodules (both originally named `execute`, so I named them in a more distinct manner).

Does it help?

Comment: Can u please explain.. To execute already imported modules again, just use reload() on the variable representing a module (eg. reload(execute1)).

Comment: Also what would happen if there are changes in any execute.py files how to compile it..

Comment: Also so it necessary to put __init__ files in dir1,dir2

Comment: **Ad. 1.** To reload a module you need to do eg. `reload(execute1)`. Why? Because if some module is already imported, it will not be reloaded by the same `import` statement, you need to do this explicitly. **Ad. 2.** If the changes occured during main script execution, then see "_Ad. 1_". If the changes occured before you executed `suite.py`, then it will be done automatically (pretty obvious). Also there is no _compilation_ (unless you mean creating `.pyc` files automatically). **Ad. 3.** Yes, it is, if you want it to be done right. You can also use `execfile()`. Do you have any questions?